# counting pixels using tensorflow and gpu

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have mask images with size (N, 256, 256), where N is a value between 1000-10000.
Each pixel has an integer value between 0-2 (0 is just background).
Unfortunately, the mask image is not encoded as (N,256,256,2)
I have a few thousands of these masks. My goal is to find the quickest method counting pixels per frame for each label (1 and 2).
Running below on one mask image with roughly 6000 frames using numpy takes < 2s.

> np.sum(ma==1,axis=(1,2))
>      np.sum(ma==2,axis=(1,2))

I expect it will take a few hours to run on entire data if I use single process, and maybe less than an hour if I use multiprocessing (CPU).
I'm curious if I can make it even faster if I use GPU. It seems easy to implement the part summing a tensor on axes, but I don't find how I can implement the `ma==1` part on tensorflow.
I thought about making the input to encoded shape (N,256,256,2) first and pass to the tensor placeholder, but realized it would take even longer than above to make an array with that shape.
Or, is there a better way to implementing pixel count on this mask data using tensorflow?

Comment: I am not really convinced it will make a huge difference, since such task takes linear time, and loading the image into the GPU memory will take linear time as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Think about what's going on in the background

Roughly the following steps are done twice in your original implementation:

- Loading the whole array from memory, prove if a value equals the desired value
- Writing the results back to memory (the temporary array is as large as your input array,np.uint8 assumed)
- Loading the whole array into memory and sum up the results
- Writing the results back to memory

It should be clear that this is a quite suboptimal implementation parallelized or not. I could not do it any better in a pure vectorized numpy way, but there are tools available (Numba, Cython) where you can implement this task in a more direct and paralellized way.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

#Create some data
N=10000
images=np.random.randint(0, high=3, size=(N,256,256), dtype=np.uint8)

def sum_orig(ma):
  A=np.sum(ma==1,axis=(1,2))
  B=np.sum(ma==2,axis=(1,2))
  return A,B

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def sum_mod(ma):
  A=np.zeros(ma.shape[0],dtype=np.uint32)
  B=np.zeros(ma.shape[0],dtype=np.uint32)

  #parallel loop
  for i in nb.prange(ma.shape[0]):
    AT=0
    BT=0
    for j in range(ma.shape[1]):
      for k in range(ma.shape[2]):
        if (ma[i,j,k]==1):
          AT+=1
        if (ma[i,j,k]==2):
          BT+=1

    A[i]=AT
    B[i]=BT

  return A,B

#Warm up
#The funtion is compiled at the first call
[A,B]=sum_mod(images)
t1=time.time()
[A,B]=sum_mod(images)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
[A_,B_]=sum_orig(images)
print(time.time()-t1)

#check if it works correctly
print(np.allclose(A,A_))
print(np.allclose(B,B_))
```

**Performance**

```
improved_version: 0.06s
original_version: 2.07s
speedup: 33x
```