# Improve the execution speed using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following for loop and want to use numpy vectorizing, boolean, mask arrays etc to improve the execution speed. arr is a numpy array

```
def translate(arr, x=0):
    arr1 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr1.shape[1]):
            if i + x < arr1.shape[0] and i + x > 0:
                arr1[i,j] = arr[i+x,j]
            if i + x < 0 or i + x > arr1.shape[0]:
                arr1[i,j] = 255
    return arr1
```

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Edit: instead of 255, when (i+x) <0, it should be arr[i,j]

```
def translate(arr, x=0):
    arr1 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr1.shape[1]):
            if i + x < arr1.shape[0] and i + x > 0:
                arr1[i,j] = arr[i+x,j]
            if i + x < 0 or i + x > arr1.shape[0]:
                arr1[i,j] = arr[i,j]
    return arr1
```

Comment: May I know what's the element's data type in your array?

Comment: Its numpy array, edited the question to include this info

Comment: I think your arr is ndarray and ndarray.size won't return a tuple so cannot do size[0] and size[1]. Do you mean ``.shape`` instead?

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, it is shape, size will give the total number of elements in the ndarray

Comment: what is the shape of arr?

Comment: You can simply compile your function using Numba. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011917/4045774 The performance is usually on par or often better than vectorized solutions. In some cases it makes even sense to go from a vectorized solution to loops. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756977/4045774

Comment: @HaleemurAli it is 184*184

Comment: @max9111 I have execution time issues, so need  a faster solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @Paul Panzer solution didn't give out the same output as your function, I revised on his work by trying boolean array. Hopefully its what you want.

**Code:**

```
def my_translate(arr, x=0):
    arr = arr.copy()
    if x == 0:
        return arr.copy()
    elif x > 0:
        replacement1 = np.zeros(arr.shape)
        replacement1[:-x] = arr[x:]
    else:
        replacement1 = np.zeros(arr.shape)
        replacement1[-x:] = arr[:x]
    replacement2 = np.zeros(arr.shape)+255 # Array filled with 255 for second logic
    l = [np.repeat(i,arr.shape[1]) for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
    firstlooplogic1 = np.asarray(l)+x < arr.shape[0]
    firstlooplogic2 = np.asarray(l)+x > 0
    secondlooplogic1 = np.asarray(l)+x > arr.shape[0]
    secondlooplogic2 = np.asarray(l)+x < 0

    part1logic = np.logical_and(firstlooplogic1,firstlooplogic2)
    part2logic = np.logical_or(secondlooplogic1,secondlooplogic2)

    part1 = part1logic*replacement1
    part2 = part2logic*replacement2
    part3 = ((part1 == 0) * (part2 == 0)) * arr       
    return (part1 + part2 +part3).astype(arr.dtype)
```

**Result:**

```
arr = 3 - np.maximum.outer(*2*(np.abs(np.arange(-3, 4)),))
output1 = my_translate(arr,-2) #output from my function
output2 = translate(arr,-2)    #output from your function above
np.array_equal(output1,output2)
>Out[10]: True
```

Basically, I just break down your nested for-loop into boolean array and do the operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot R.yan

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that does what I think you want to do (shift the original array up or down and fill the empty space with `255`)

```
>>> def translate_vectorized(arr, x=0):
...     if x == 0:
...         return arr.copy()
...     out = np.full(arr.shape, 255)
...     if x < 0:
...         out[-x:] = arr[:x]
...     else:
...         out[:-x] = arr[x:]
...     return out
```

Demo

```
>>> arr = 3 - np.maximum.outer(*2*(np.abs(np.arange(-3, 4)),))
>>> arr
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> 
>>> translate_vectorized(arr, -2)
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   2,   2,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   3,   2,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   2,   2,   1,   0]])
>>> translate_vectorized(arr, 1)
array([[  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   2,   2,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   3,   2,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   2,   2,   2,   1,   0],
       [  0,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

Comment: Thanks, @Paul Panzer

Comment: How will you use it to translate left or right, instead of up and down?

Comment: I tried arr2[:,[:-x]] = arr1[:,[x:]] , but not working

Comment: @SurabhiAmitChembra try `arr2[:, :-x] = arr1[:, x:]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have optimized your solution a bit (better cache utilization leading to about 30% speedup). But if you leave it as it is, it will be also OK. The only thing you have to do on numpy code with excessive looping is compiling it. This can be done using Numba or with a bit more work with Cython.

The compiled version should be about 3000 times faster than your solution. The parallelization isn't really necessary here (only about 20% speedup) due to running in a memory bottleneck.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def translate(arr, x):
    arr1 = np.empty(arr.shape,dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(arr1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr1.shape[1]):
            arr1[i,j]=arr[i,j]
            if i + x < arr1.shape[0] and i + x > 0:
                arr1[i,j] = arr[i+x,j]
            if i + x < 0 or i + x > arr1.shape[0]:
                arr1[i,j] = arr[i,j]
    return arr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Tried using numpy.roll(arr, shift_amount). It also works, but elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the first. So, when (i+x) is less than shape[0], it can be used.

```
if (i+x) < arr1.shape[0]:
    arr2 = np.roll(arr1,x)
```